# SQL List of year from this year to 5 years back, then used as parameter in stored sproc

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

First I need to create a sproc that will give me just a list of years from this year back to 5 years before this year. I was thinking of somehow using a table variable?

After that I need to use that value as a parameter in another sproc. How would I then say show all Dates that contain the year that is picked? I know how to write the parameter and everything I just need the Where clause part of it.

The date in the column are like this 2010/01/30 00:00.000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part One:

```
Declare @Years Table (int year primary Key Not Null)
Declare @Yr integer Set @Yr = Year(getDate())
Declare @tYr Integer Set @tYr = @Yr
while @Yr > @TYr - 5 Begin
   Insert @Years(year) Values (@Yr)
   Set @Yr = @Yr - 1
End
```

Part TWO:  (I assume you mean "Show all Dates That contain a year in the five year span" ??)

```
Where Year(dateColumn) In (Select year from @Years)
```

-- But this is not SARGable, so I would reccomend instead,

```
Where dateColumn Between DateAdd(year, Year(getDate())-1905, 0) 
                     And DateAdd(year, Year(getDate())-1899, 0)
```